# graphing $\frac{x^3-x+1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to graph:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3-x+1}{x^2}$$

so I took the first derivative:

$$f'(x) = \frac{x^3+x-2}{x^3}$$

but this function is hard to find the signals. In other words, it's hard to find where the function is increasing or decreasing. Also, the second derivative is even worse. I'm assuming it shouldn't be all that hard to find the signals, because it's as exercise on a book.

Any ideas? Do I really have to find the roots of the numerator?

Comment: Does writing it as $$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ make it *any* easier?

Comment: From first derivative, you can see that $f'(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow  x = 1$

Comment: The easiest way to freehand graph a function is to make a table of values, then place those points on the coordinate system.

Comment: @EdwardJiang I think it's still useful to have a sense where the local maxima and minima are so you don't inadvertently draw one on the right of a tabulated point when the actual local extremum is left of that point. (Though if you also tabulate some first derivatives, that also is a way to help avoid that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study of sign of $f':$

Write the numerator as

$$x^3+x-2=(x-1)(x^2+x+2).$$ Now, $(x-1)(x^2+x+2)=0\iff x=1.$ So,

$$\begin{array}{ccc} x & (-\infty,1) & (1,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign}(x^3+x-2) & - & +\end{array}$$

It is clear that $x^3=0\iff x=0.$ Now

$$\begin{array}{ccc} x & (-\infty,0) & (0,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign}(x^3) & - & +\end{array}$$

Thus

$$\begin{array}{cccc} x & (-\infty,0)& (0,1) & (1,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign}(f') & + & - & +\end{array}$$
So, $f$ is increasing in $(-\infty,0),$ decreasing in $(0,1)$ and increasing in $(1,\infty).$ Since it changes from decreasing to increasing at $x=1$ it has a local minimum at $x=1.$ (Note that $0$ doesn't belong to the domain.)

Note that the study of $$f''(x)=\frac{2(3-x)}{x^4}$$ is simpler. Repeating the same process:

$$2(3-x)=0\iff x=3$$ and

$$\begin{array}{ccc} x & (-\infty,3) & (3,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign}(2(3-x)) & + & -\end{array}$$

$$x^4=0\iff x=0$$ and

$$\begin{array}{ccc} x & (-\infty,0) & (0,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign}(x^4) & + & -\end{array}$$ Finally

$$\begin{array}{cccc} x & (-\infty,0) & (0,3) & (3,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign}(f'') & + & + & -\end{array}$$ Thus $f$ is convex on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,3)$ and concave on $(3,\infty).$ Since it changes curvature at $x=3$ $f$ has an inflection point at $x=3.$